# What is the difference between CSS classes and Variables

Tags: css

I’m working my way through the freecodecamp front end curriculum and from what I understand both classes and variables can be used to minimise code and make code more easily maintainable. Can anyone explain where a CSS variable would be best used over just creating a class and applying styling in that way?

Thanks,

Comment: You are comparing things that cannot be compared

Comment: @TemaniAfif See [Sass CSS variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) and W3C's [CSS Custom Properties, aka CSS Variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)

Comment: @RonRoyston I know both of them ;) and the question it not related to SASS ... the question is comparing *classes* with *CSS variables* and there is nothing to compare between them ... each one has a specific use. And at the end this is will be opinion based.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Are you able to explain the use of custom properties for me? I know how the classes work but have gotten confused regarding when I would need to use the variables?

Comment: there is no a specific *when* you can use them .. you simply need to understand that CSS variable will avoid you to repeat some value. You can for example define a color using CSS variable and use it all over your CSS and whenever you want to change the color you only need to change the variable and not all your code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could that also not be achieved through creating a class for instance .custom-color and then inserting that class wherever it is needed, then whenever you want to change the color you just have to edit the colour set within the class?

Comment: no, because with a class you can define a color for a particular property ... but with variable you only define the value that you can use with different properties, here is a simple example : https://jsfiddle.net/yju40xwn/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif That explains it perfectly thank you! So the custom property is used for storing a specific value eg black or 50px, while classes are used to store a number of different properties and their values (or declared variables).

Comment: yes let's say this is the *minimal* conclusion that will make you have a clear view ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a higher level of attribute:value, it affects the targeted attribute:value inside other classes or ids. Another way of doing it is using double class in the affected elements. For example in the freecodecamp lesson, the penguin has black head and arms. Use class (head, arm etc)  for the shape, margin etc and class2 for the color instead of using variable. e.g. ..  and so on..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,the variables can be defined inside classes.

Classes we created might have other values like font-family,width,border etc along with our variable.So if we have to change only one value,say:color, we only need to change the variable.
If classes alone are used we  might need to create classes for each colours separately & include that in which ever elements we need, which is tedious.

please refer to the penguin section of fcc ("https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/basic-css/use-css-variables-to-change-several-elements-at-once") for clarifying the same.

Answer (score -2):

Think of a CSS class as a placeholder. Create it once then apply it multiple times.  If you want to change it, a single change updates all places it is applied to.

```
.custom-div {
  color: red;
  font-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

A CSS id is reserved for use on a single element on a page. This is why your browser can jump directly to `#my-section`.

There is an effort to extend [CSS support for custom properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/), sometimes referred to as CSS variables. SASS is an example of a system to introduce CSS variables.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply! I’m reasonably sure how both classes and ID’s work, but the custom properties (variables) has just been introduced and has threw me off a little. I’m a little confused as to when you would choose to use a custom property over applying a class or ID to an element?

Comment: CSS custom classes, i.e. CSS variables, only come into play for very large websites. The popular example of their application is for theme colors. Traditionally, colors are applied to several CSS classes such as borders, backgrounds, font colors, etc. With traditional CSS classes you can't pass `color: myColorVar;` so you end up having to `find/replace` several colors vs using a CSS variable.